# java - radiogroup with on checked changed listener in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I'm new to android programming. Maybe you can help me with this.

I've got:
Fragment
RadioGroup with 2 radio buttons
EditText

My goal is:

By default the first radio button is selected and the edittext was disabled or uneditable
then when i select the 2nd radio button it enables the edittext and setfocus to it
And also vice versa.
When i select again the first radio button it will disable the edittext.
This were all inside one of my fragments.

Can someone help me for the code?
Also another question, can i save the previously selected radio button using shared preferences so it will be loaded when i open my application?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok first set your EditText in visible in xml or java using this code snippet `android:visibility="invisible"` or in java code `myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` while pressing the other radio button make it visible by using this code `myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
Then com e to your second question you can save your radio button selection using share preference by setting a variable

**save**

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("your_key", "yourValue");
    editor.commit();
```

**get**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myValue = sp.getString("your_key", "defaultValue");
```

The `SharedPreference` interface gives you access to the an `xml` file, and a easy way to modify it through its editor. The file is stored in `/data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/` and you can access it onlu through this SharedPreference API

Comment: My other question is, should i add a specific onclick listener on the radio button? cause after this i will add a button with different function which will also need a specific on click listener?